# Create an API call for CoinTracking API in GoogleSheets

Tags: api

I am trying to call the CoinTracking.info API from GoogleSheets in order to get a list of my crypto balances per coin.

API documentation: https://cointracking.info/api/api.php

The documentation suggests using a 3rd party add-on called "CryptoSheet", but I would like to avoid this if possible, since they require read/write access to my GoogleSheets documents.

I have tried the following code, but receieve the following error:
{"success":0,"error":"NO_METHOD","error_msg":"ERROR: Method not set"}

---

```
API_Public_Key = { 'TEST':'mypublickey' }
API_Private_Key = { 'TEST':'myprivatekey' }

function KAPI_Private(acc_id, parameters) {
  Utilities.sleep(Math.random() * 100)
  
  api_key = 'mypublickey'
  api_secret = 'myprivatekey'
  api_nonce = Date.now().toString()
  api_post = 'nonce=' + api_nonce + '&' + parameters
  
  methodnoncepost = 'POST'+ api_nonce + api_post
  
  api_hmac = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, methodnoncepost, api_secret)
  
  api_signature = api_hmac
  
  http_options = {'method':'POST', 'payload':api_post, 'headers':{'API-Key':api_key, 'API-Sign':api_hmac}}
  http_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cointracking.info/api/v1/', http_options)
  api_data = http_response.getContentText()
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue(api_data)
return api_data
}

function KAPI_Balance(acc_id) {
  acc_balances_json = JSON.parse(KAPI_Private(acc_id, 'GetBalance', ''))
  acc_balances = new Array
  for ( name in acc_balances_json['result'] ) {
    acc_balances.push([name, parseFloat(acc_balances_json['result'][name]['balance'])])
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that the getBalance method is not recognised in your query (you need to label it with "method="). The header keys are also incorrect.

Try this:

```
function KAPI_Private(acc_id, parameters) {
  Utilities.sleep(Math.random() * 100)

  api_key = 'mypublickey'
  api_secret = 'myprivatekey'
  api_nonce = Date.now().toString()
  api_post = 'method=' + parameters + '&' + 'nonce=' + api_nonce //Modified

  api_hmac = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, api_post, api_secret) //Modified

  api_signature = api_hmac.map(function(e) { //Added
    var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
    return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
  }).join("");

  http_options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'payload': api_post,
    'headers': {
      'Key': api_key,
      'Sign': api_signature
     }
   } //Modified
  http_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cointracking.info/api/v1/', 
  http_options)
  api_data = http_response.getContentText()

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue(api_data)
  return api_data
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).